# Adding an additional tag to this AWS CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am trying to query instances in my account by this info but I Need to also add owner email and can't seem to figure it out.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{PublicIP:PublicIpAddress,Type:InstanceType,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Status:State.Name}"  \
--filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=*" "Name=tag:Name,Values='*'"  \
--output table
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "owner email"? There is no concept of 'resource owners' in AWS. Resources belong to an Account, not to Users. Is it, perhaps, a tag that you have added to each instance?

Comment: Why are you using wildcards like `Name=instance-state-name,Values=*`? If you do not wish to limit the result set, then simply do not specify the filter.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sorry I am new to writing queries like these. I wish it was written better. Essentially I want to list instance Id, I wish the region, the name tag and the owner_email tag which is yes a custom tag we have as well as the instance typ.

Comment: Can't you just add the other tag, just like you did with `Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value`?